# Does QGraphicsTextItem support vertical-center alignment?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qt4.7

Basically, I want to know why the combination of text alignment flags and `setPageSize` doesn't end up with text centered in the display.

The following program does nearly exactly what I want, except that the text ends up centered only horizontally.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QTextDocument>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   QGraphicsView view;
   view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
   view.setFrameStyle(0);
   view.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black)));
   mainWindow->setCentralWidget(&view);

   QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 640, 480);
   QGraphicsTextItem textItem;
   textItem.setTextWidth(640);
   textItem.document()->setPageSize(QSizeF(640, 480));
   textItem.document()->setDocumentMargin(0);
   textItem.document()->setDefaultTextOption(QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter));
   textItem.setDefaultTextColor(QColor(Qt::white));
   textItem.setFont(QFont("monospace", 18, 63));
   textItem.setHtml("Center me!");
   scene.addItem(&textItem);
   textItem.setVisible(true);

   view.setScene(&scene);
   mainWindow->show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

I should also note that this project is constrained to Qt 4.7.1.

How do I align text both horizontally and vertically in the center of a `QGraphicsView` using a `QGraphicsTextItem`? I'm fine with a stylesheet-based solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

[This bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13467) indicates that the `QTextDocument` (the underlying text rendering object) specifically does not attempt to vertical alignment. After looking about, most workarounds fall into two categories. For simple (i.e. single-line plain-text) applications, implement a proxy item that renders the text in its overloaded `paint` method as so:

```
class MyProxyGraphicsItem: public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    explicit MyProxyGraphicsItem(QString text, QRectF geometry, QGraphicsItem *parent=0) :
        QGraphicsItem(parent), text(text), geometry(geometry)
        {}
    virtual ~MyProxyGraphicsItem() {}
    QRectF boundingRect() const { return geometry; }
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
         painter->drawText(geometry, text, Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    }
private:
    QRectF geometry;
    QString text;
}
```

For multi-line plain-text or rich-text (HTML), use a `QLabel` in stead as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QLabel>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   QGraphicsView view;
   view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
   view.setFrameStyle(0);
   view.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black)));
   mainWindow->setCentralWidget(&view);

   QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 640, 480);
   QLabel label("<div style=\"color:white;\">Center me!</div>");
   label.setWordWrap(true);
   label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
   label.setFont(QFont("monospace", 18, 63));
   scene.addWidget(&label)->setGeometry(QRectF(0,0,480,640));

   view.setScene(&scene);
   mainWindow->show();

   return a.exec();
}
```